# Use a excel cell reference to indicate tab name inside a formula?

Tags: excel

[image: Example]

I have a document that has 52 tabs, one for each week. They're named 
`Week (1), ...,Week (52)`. In the 53rd tab, I have a summary of the data inputted into every tab.

The idea is that my supervisor copies and pastes data per week, hiding the tab as she completes that week, and the 53rd summary page will show the entire year broken down per week.

My problem is, the formula for one of the cells is `=SUMIF('Week (1)'!$B:$B,B3,'Week (1)'!$G:$G)` where the point is to add up the column G in Week (1) for each entry where B3 equals the corresponding cell in Week (1) column B on the same row.

Since I have this copied 52 times, I would ordinarily have to manually enter each tab into the various different formulas, replacing Week (1) with Week (2), etc and so forth until Week (52).

Is there a way to instead have the following formula:

`=SUMIF('[REFERENCE TO CELL CONTAINING TAB NAME]'!$B:$B,B3,'[REFERENCE]'!$G:$G)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `INDIRECT` you can create a sheet reference using a cell value. Instead of your example in the picture:

`=SUMIF('[E1]1!$B:$B,F3,'[E3]'!$G:$G)`

You could use:

`=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&E1&"'!$B:$B"),F3,INDIRECT("'"&E3&"'!$G:$G"))`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the function EVAL

```
EVAL("Week (1)")
```

More details here
https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/62067-eval-function-without-morefunc-add.html

Comment: `EVALUATE` only works in named ranges and VBA. The link seems to suggest this `EVAL` formula is a UDF based on `EVALUATE`. If there is actually an answer here, it's buried!

Comment: Yes I was suggesting that VBA could be used for a volatile function  
  
`Function Eval(Ref As String)  
     Application.Volatile  
     Eval = Evaluate(Ref)  
End Function`