# Copy the cell value into a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate the average in excel with two columns with the cell address data.

Here is an example:

```
Start    End      Average
$CL$2    $CP$2    =average($CL$2:$CP$2)
$AD$3    $AT$3    =average($AD$3:$AT$3)
$AD$4    $AT$4    =average($AD$4:$AT$4)
$AD$5    $AT$5    =average($AD$5:$AT$5)
```

When I click on the Cell it references the cell with the value in it and the average formula doesn't work

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the [`INDIRECT` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a excel cell reference to indicate tab name inside a formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914390/use-a-excel-cell-reference-to-indicate-tab-name-inside-a-formula)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `INDIRECT` function to return a reference specified by a text string - in this case, your starting and ending cell addresses, concatenated with the colon `:`.

For example:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(A2&":"&B2))
```

[image]